# WPN-XM control panel crash after restart

Tags: wpn-xm

This is very weird problem I am having and I can't seem to be able to find anything on google. 
I installed WPN-XM and it started fine on first run. But, when I restart the machine, it crashes. 
Details below..

UPDATE: It seems like only that wpn-xm.exe is crashing. I could run the bat files to start daemons. and access the server..

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: wpn-xm.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    02abf978
  Fault Module Name:    Qt5Widgets.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   01d8d4c8
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00134e6b
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Screenshot>>http://i61.tinypic.com/fbclrl.jpg

Comment: I'm not constantly monitoring Stackoverflow of the wpn-xm tag. So, for faster support, please post over here: https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues . Thank you for trying out WPN-XM.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when Daemons are set up to start on launch of wpn-xm.exe. I changed autostart demons to 0 in wpn-xm.ini and control panel is able to launch again.

Answer (score 0):

The autostart issue is fixed with v0.8.1 of the Server Control Panel.
Please update.

https://github.com/WPN-XM/server-control-panel/releases/tag/0.8.1